# How to get WS-Security certificate to be accepted by Java application

Tags: java, soapui, ws-security, xml-signature

So I've been struggling with WS-Security for some time now, slowly making progress. First let me briefly describe my setup. I have Java application running in a tomcat, which offers a webservice endpoint (using Spring). I want incoming messages to be signed. I am testing with SoapUI. So after a long struggle, I got the server as far as checking incoming messages for a signature and I also got SoapUI, to sign outgoing messages. However, the server keeps rejecting the certificate and I'm not sure where I'm doing something wrong, i.e. am I sending the wrong certificate information with my test requests, or have I not correctly maintained the certificate in the truststore. Following is an example of a request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="http://movilitas.com/movilizer/v7" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-7" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2011-06-30T12:51:33.407Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2011-06-30T12:53:13.407Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <ds:Signature Id="Signature-6" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-2">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>OiRQ2oXbajnnrSGsbOALT2i6brs=</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>
                fmtFMSccFcwEfL1M8qgQ...
            </ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-C3B38A939F7D63D51F13094382933988">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-C3B38A939F7D63D51F13094382933989" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                  <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
                                      ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3SubjectKeyIdentifier">
                        MIICbzCCAdgCAQEwDQ... 
                    </wsse:KeyIdentifier>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      [...]
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now the content I have in  is the same as the one I get, when I export the certificate from my truststore (the base64 encoded version of the certificate). The error I get when I send the request is the following:

```
Jul 5, 2011 4:42:23 PM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.KeySelectorImpl resolve
SEVERE: WSS1353: Error occurred while resolving key information
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: No Matching public key for MIICbzCCAdgCAQEwDQ... subject key identifier found
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.getCertificate(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:617)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.KeySelectorImpl.resolve(KeySelectorImpl.java:385)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.dsig.KeySelectorImpl.select(KeySelectorImpl.java:232)
    ...
```

Am I missing something? Something big? Or small? Is this what I am actually supposed to send as KeyIdentifier? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not send along the certificate itself, only the reference to the certificate - the Subject Key identifier. You either have to store your partners' public certificates in a truststore (keystore) or you must include the binary security token inside your message. See http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16785/wss-v1.1-spec-os-x509TokenProfile.pdf section 3.3.2 for details.